# Angular Material - data table is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, typescript

I got stuck to this problem for quite sometime.

Need help.
Relatively very new to angular.io and implementing with asp.net mvc. For UI library considering angular material. Other controls seems to be working fine but 'Datatable' seems to be not working as expected.
When Component containing 'Datatable' is tried to load in application, first time it is not getting loaded through angular route. When next time again it is clicked or if we work on any control. Datatable is shown.

I tried to add respective part of code in plunkr at
https://plnkr.co/edit/Lp2l0swFwlDI12a9E2vr?p=preview

but plunkr is not able to run that.

Anybody have any idea what can be problem, you can have look at code from plukr link given above?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @MisterPositive added plunker link. It was not shown due to syntax problem.